# Why does my first hash value disappear in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Why does the hash remove the first value `apple:2` when I print the output?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ("apple:2", "pie:4", "cake:2");
my %wordcount;
our $curword;
our $curnum;
foreach (@array) {
    ($curword, $curnum) = split(":",$_);
    $wordcount{$curnum}=$curword;
}
print Dumper (\%wordcount);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl hash can only have unique keys, so

```
$wordcount{2} = "apple";
```

is later overwritten by

```
$wordcount{2} = "cake";
```

Answer (score 5):

What you probably wanted to do was:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ("apple:2", "pie:4", "cake:2");
my %wordcount;
for my $entry (@array) {
    my ($word, $num) = split /:/, $entry;
    push @{$wordcount{$num}}, $word;
}

print Dumper (\%wordcount);
```

This way, each entry in `%wordcount` relates a word count to an array of the words which appear that many times (assuming the `:n` in the notation indicates the count).

It is OK to be a beginner, but it is not OK to assume other people can read your mind.

Also, don't use global variables (`our`) when lexically scoped (`my`) will do.